# Group completion of labelled configuration space on Euclidean spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, loop-spaces, configuration-spaces

In the lecture notes [The Homology of $\mathcal{C}_{n+1}$-spaces, $n\geq 0$, F. Cohen](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/BOOKS/homo_iter.pdf), page 225 -226, it is obtained that there is a group completion on homology
$$
\alpha_n: C(\mathbb{R}^n;X)\to \Omega^n\Sigma^n X.$$
Moreover, I find that
$$
\Omega^n\Sigma^nS^0=\Omega^n S^n=\bigsqcup_{q\in \mathbb{Z}}\{f\in [S^n,S^n]_*\mid \deg (f)=q\}.
$$
Let $$
\{f\in [S^n,S^n]_*\mid \deg (f)=q\}=\Omega_q^nS^n$$
then
$$
\Omega^n\Sigma^nS^0=\bigsqcup_{q\in\mathbb{Z}}\Omega_q^nS^n.
$$
I find in some references that
$$
C(\mathbb{R}^n;S^0)=\bigsqcup_{k\geq 0}F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k.
$$
Let $\alpha_{n,k}$ be the restriction of $\alpha_n$ to $F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k$.

**Question:** I want to obtain the ring structure of $H^*(F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k;\mathbb{Z}_2)$. Is there any way to obtain it? Do we have a well-defined map $$\alpha_{n,k}: F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k\to\Omega_k^nS^n$$ that induces a ring isomorphism
$$
H^*(\Omega_k^nS^n;\mathbb{Z}_2)\to H^*(F(\mathbb{R}^n,k)/\Sigma_k;\mathbb{Z}_2)?
$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a a well-defined map from $F(\mathbb R^n,k)/\Sigma_k \to \Omega^n_k S^n$ but it only induces an iso on $H^*$ for $* \leq k/2$.

Comment: Where is this actually proven, that the scanning map ("electric field map") is an iso on (co)homology in degree lower than half the number of particles in the configuration? I see it stated without proof on p.1 of Segal 73 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/configuration+space+of+points#Segal73 attributed there to Barratt-Priddy 72 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+completion+theorem#BarrattPriddy72 and to Quillen 94 https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+completion+theorem#Quillen94 but I haven't spotted the statement, nor its proof, in these references yet (of Quillen 94 I only have few pages...)

Comment: I suppose one is to use a) that the scanning map exhibits the group completion (Segal 73, Theorem 1) b) the group completion theorem https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/group+completion+theorem and c) the homological stability of unordered configuration spaces in degrees below half the number of points. (e.g. Randall-Williams 13, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/configuration+space+of+points#HomologyAndStabilization)